# Translating "how is ...?" and "how was ...?"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, tiempos-verbales, cópulas

What are the options for translating the phrase "how is" or "how was," as in:

- How's the steak?
- How is your day so far?
- How is the traffic today?

and

- How was your vacation?
- How was the meeting?
- How was your birthday yesterday?

Which of ¿Cómo es/está? and ¿Cómo fue/era/estuvo/estaba? work here, and what are the differences? What other ways are there of expressing this question?

Comment: I would like to know what is missing from this answer and its comments, in order to make it really useful to the question. The differences between `ser` and `estar` aren't the main subject of this question by the way.

Comment: @Nicolás: I'd be interested in more details on how *¿Cómo fue?* (which I've heard very often) and *¿Cómo estaba?* would be used. But otherwise great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An almost literal translation is indeed a right option:

**Present**:

> - *¿Cómo está el bistec?*
> - *¿Cómo está siendo tu día hasta ahora?*   →  (you should use present continuous (gerund) in case the day hasn't finished yet).
> - *¿Cómo está el tráfico hoy?*

**Preterite**:

> - *¿Cómo estuvieron tus vacaciones?*
> - *¿Cómo estuvo la reunión?*
> - *¿Cómo estuvo la celebración de tu cumpleaños ayer?*

Although you can use as well ***qué tal ...*** (in this case the verb can be omitted):

> - *¿Qué tal (está / estuvo) el bistec?*
> - *¿Qué tal (está siendo / ha sido) tu día hasta ahora?*
> - ... and so on ...

---

The main distinction between `ser` and `estar` in this case is the classical one regarding these verbs: <sub>(this issue isn't the main subject of the question by the way)</sub>

- **Estar**: must be used related to things limited in time. That is to say, when you ask about a feature of something limited to the time when the conversation is being made. You sould not use this verb to ask for a permanent feature of something.
- **Ser**: must be used when you ask about a permanent or inherent feature of something, or about a feature that repeats in time.

For example:

> - ***¿Cómo es el bistec?***: You could hear (or ask) such a question when you don't know at all what a `bistec` is (e.g. you come from a vegan family or town), and you want to know what it's made from, what are its features, etc.
> - ***¿Cómo está el bistec?***: You will hear (or ask) this question when you want to know how tasty or delicious is the meal being eaten by the person you are talking to.

---

A succinct resource you could read to grasp the difference between *ser* and *estar*:

- ['Ser' and 'Estar': Verbs for 'To Be'](http://spanish.about.com/cs/verbs/a/servsestar.htm)

Comment: So none of the example questions would work with *ser*? Would this mean that no such questions would ever work with *ser*?

Comment: I agree on the present tense suggestions. For the past tense, I think `ser` could also work. e.g. ¿Cómo fue la reunión? That said, `estuvo` carries a meaning closer to the English equivalent of the question (and less ambiguous) than `fue`. However, I think the use of (or should I say, the preference to use) `estuvo` in that way is somewhat regional. I never ran across it until speaking with Mexican Spanish speakers over a period of time.

Comment: As far as I know, `¿cómo fue la reunión?` isn't clear enough. Don't forget that `fue` belongs not only to the verb `ser`, but also to verb `ir`.

Comment: Another verb that is sometimes used here is "andar" "¿Cómo anda el tráfico?" "¿Cómo anduvo la reunión" - though this would rather correspond to "How did the meeting go?"

Comment: @Kevin: That *fue* is from the verb *ir*. Changing the tense, you could say *¿cómo ha ido la reunión?* In some contexts, you could also ask *¿cómo ha sido la reunión?*, but that would be *what has the meeting been like?* (asking for details about what happened, who spoke in which order, what was said, etc. rather than a general overview of it)